# ubuntu server 16.04: cannot get supervisor to start automatically

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I installed supervisor on ubuntu server 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
$ sudo update-rc.d supervisor defaults
```

After rebooting, supervisor didn't get started automatically. Checked the status:

```
qinking126@nas:~$ sudo service supervisor status
[sudo] password for qinking126:
● supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
```

I'm not sure why it's inactive (dead).  What do I need to check to get it fixed?

Comment: Looks like you're using systemd. Does [this askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/19324) answer help?

Comment: @JeffSchaller thank you so much. it helps. all i need is to run "systemctl enable SERVICE.service"

Answer (score 65):

I am convinced that this issue is a packaging bug in the Supervisor package in Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems to have been caused by the switch to systemd:

- This issue was already reported upstream on the Supervisor project's issue tracker (where nothing can be fixed) in [issue 735](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/735#issuecomment-227391553).
- I was bitten by this issue a few days ago and was astonished to find that this issue was never reported to the package maintainers, even though Ubuntu 16.04 was released quite a while ago and this breaks backwards compatibility and expected behavior. This is why I decided to report this issue to the package maintainers in [bug 1594740](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740).

**I documented a simple workaround in [bug 1594740](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740) that doesn't require any configuration files to be created - you just need to enable and start the Supervisor daemon after installation of the package:**

```sh
# Make sure Supervisor comes up after a reboot.
sudo systemctl enable supervisor

# Bring Supervisor up right now.
sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

I'm not so sure that this will be fixed in Ubuntu 16.04 but at least now there's a central place to gather complaints and document workarounds (in [bug 1594740](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740), *not* in [issue 735](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/735#issuecomment-227391553)).

If anyone was bitten by this issue, consider voicing your concern in [bug 1594740](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740) to convince the package maintainers to fix this issue. Thanks!

**Update (2017-03-24):** Yesterday a fix for this issue [was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740/comments/31) to [xenial-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/supervisor) as a result of [bug 1594740](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/1594740) so new installations should no longer run into this issue.

Answer (score 12):

see here [Running supervisord automatically on startup](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisord-automatically-on-startup)

1. Create `supervisord.service` file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`and put following content into this file depending on system:

   [initscripts](https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts)
2. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. `sudo systemctl enable supervisord.service`
4. `sudo systemctl start supervisord.service`

Comment: https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/centos-systemd-etcs

Comment: Worked for me, but the path was /lib/systemd/system

Answer (score 5):

I have removed the supervisor and installed again. Then it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get purge supervisor
sudo apt-get install supervisor
cp path/to/file.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example of a file where you can put in your /lib/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisord Service

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: the default ubuntu config location is at `/etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not for my ubuntu 16.04 install. The correct location is: /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (note lack of "d" if anybody is wondering)

Comment: @Yoshi9143 you're correct :D

Answer (score 1):

apt-get install supervisor on Ubuntu 16.04.2, installs the supervisor 3.2.0 and it starts automatically on reboot.

pip install supervisor --upgrade upgrades to 3.3.1 and it does not start any more at all.

The upgrade works Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: This is the correct answer, although @anjaneyulubatta505 response was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On `CentOS` i solved it by running a cron job on startup that runs `supervisord`:

to Create the cron job 
run `crontab -e` in the terminal and then paste `@reboot /bin/supervisord`(**it must be path to the supervisord**) at the end of the jobs and save it.